# How can i open an existing Excel file using the classic asp

Tags: html, excel, asp-classic

I have an immediate requirement where I need to open some specific excel sheets from an existing Excel file which resides on a system. I want to know how this can be accomplished using **Classic ASP**. I tried searching on the internet but couldn't find anything specific. Need some suggestions...:)

I hope this makes sense

I tried below code but all in vain.

```
<html> 
<body bgcolor="white" text="black"> 

        <%Dim xlObject, xlBook,wks Set xlObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application") xlObject.visible = False 
        Set xlBook = xlObject.Workbooks.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Final Help file 11june13.xls") 
        Set wks = xlObject.ActiveWorkBook.Worksheets(1) 
        response.Write("permbajtja e qelizes eshte: "&wks.Cells(3,1)) 
        xlBook.Close xlObject.Quit 
        Set wks = Nothing 
        Set xlBook = Nothing 
        Set xlObject = Nothing %> 
    </form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find some code? Something that you wrote yet? Why would you want to open a file? Which are your motivation.

Comment: I tried below code but all in vain.
`html>
<body bgcolor="white" text="black">
<%Dim xlObject, xlBook,wks
Set xlObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlObject.visible = False 

Set xlBook = xlObject.Workbooks.open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Final Help 

file 11june13.xls")
Set wks = xlObject.ActiveWorkBook.Worksheets(1)
response.Write("permbajtja e qelizes eshte: "&wks.Cells(3,1))
xlBook.Close
xlObject.Quit
Set wks = Nothing
Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlObject = Nothing %>
</form></body>
</html>`

Answer (score -3):

For example, how you can show your Excel file into a webbrowser, a simple example in C#. Are you planning to write it in pure ASP, or in ASP.NET?

```
public static void ConvertExcelFile(String excelFile)
{
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xls = null;
        try
        {
            excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            object missing = Type.Missing;
            object trueObject = true;
            excel.Visible = false;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            xls = excel.Workbooks.Open(excelFile, missing, trueObject, missing,

                    missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing,

                    missing, missing, missing);
            object format = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlHtml;
            IEnumerator wsEnumerator=excel.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.GetEnumerator();
            int i = 1;
            while (wsEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet wsCurrent =
                (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wsEnumerator.Current;
                String outputFile =excelFile + "." + i.ToString() + ".html";
                wsCurrent.SaveAs(outputFile, format, missing, missing, missing,
                missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
                ++i;
            }
            excel.Quit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error accessing Excel document.\n\n" +
            ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This can be found under: http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/477965-excel-files-html-using-c

Comment: Thank you  for the all the help but i know how to accomplish this task in c#. Would you please give some suggestions with the coding using classic ASP. Need to complete this as per the company requirement.

Comment: You can find a more deep solution here: http://www.shotdev.com/asp/asp-excel/asp-open-excel-on-specified-worksheet/

Comment: I will look into it and put the feedback here. Thank you very much